# Combine array items uniquely regarding order and duplication

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have an array:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'f']
```

and now want to get possible combinations of two, but the order of the letters is not important. So the result **should be**:

```
[['a', 'a'],['a', 'b'],['a', 'f'],['b', 'f']]
```

I tried

```
a.product(a)
```

But that of course returned ALL possible combinations, not regarding that the order is not important and that double results should be removed:

```
[["a", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "f"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "f"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "f"], ["f", "a"], ["f", "b"], ["f", "a"], ["f", "f"]]
```

I could solve these issues in loops, but I wonder if there is some ruby array/hash magic that could help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) and `uniq` with `sort`:

```
a.combination(2).to_a.uniq(&:sort)
# => [["a", "b"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "f"], ["b", "f"]]
```

#### [Demonstration](https://repl.it/N5CJ)

Comment: I believe `to_a` is not needed here.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: it is, because combination without a block returns an instance of `Enumerator` instead of an `Array` one